# Joining data in spark data frames using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark dataframe in Scala as below -

```
val df = Seq(
(0,0,0,0.0,0),
(1,0,0,0.1,1),
(0,1,0,0.11,1),
(0,0,1,0.12,1),
(1,1,0,0.24,2),
(1,0,1,0.27,2),
(0,1,1,0.3,2),
(1,1,1,0.4,3)
).toDF("A","B","C","rate","total")
```

Here is how it looks like

```
scala> df.show
+---+---+---+----+-----+
|  A|  B|  C|rate|total|
+---+---+---+----+-----+
|  0|  0|  0| 0.0|    0|
|  1|  0|  0| 0.1|    1|
|  0|  1|  0|0.11|    1|
|  0|  0|  1|0.12|    1|
|  1|  1|  0|0.24|    2|
|  1|  0|  1|0.27|    2|
|  0|  1|  1| 0.3|    2|
|  1|  1|  1| 0.4|    3|
+---+---+---+----+-----+
```

A,B and C are channels in this case. 0 and 1 represent absence and presence of channels respectively. 2^3 shows 8 combinations in the data-frame with a column 'total' giving row-wise sum of these 3 channels.

The individual probabilities of these channel occurrence can be given by -

```
scala> val oneChannelCase = df.filter($"total" === 1).toDF()

scala> oneChannelCase.show()
+---+---+---+----+-----+
|  A|  B|  C|rate|total|
+---+---+---+----+-----+
|  1|  0|  0| 0.1|    1|
|  0|  1|  0|0.11|    1|
|  0|  0|  1|0.12|    1|
+---+---+---+----+-----+
```

However, I am interested in only pair-wise probabilities of these channels which is given by -

```
scala> val probs = df.filter($"total" === 2).toDF()

scala> probs.show()
+---+---+---+----+-----+
|  A|  B|  C|rate|total|
+---+---+---+----+-----+
|  1|  1|  0|0.24|    2|
|  1|  0|  1|0.27|    2|
|  0|  1|  1| 0.3|    2|
+---+---+---+----+-----+
```

What I would like to do is - append 3 new columns to these "probs" dataframe that shows individual probabilities. Below is the output that I am looking for -

```
A   B   C   rate    prob_A   prob_B   prob_C
1   1   0   0.24      0.1      0.11      0
1   0   1   0.27      0.1      0         0.12                     
0   1   1   0.3       0        0.11      0.12
```

To make thing clearer, the first row of output result shows A=1, B=1, C=0. Hence the individual probabilities for A=0.1, B=0.11 and C=0 is appended to the probs dataframe respectively. Similarly, for second row, A=1, B=0, C=1 shows individual probabilities for A=0.1, B=0 and C=0.12 is appended to the probs dataframe respectively.

Here is what I have tried -

```
scala> val channels = df.columns.filter(v => !(v.contains("rate") |  v.contains("total")))
#channels: Array[String] = Array(A, B, C)


scala> val pivotedProb = channels.map(v => f"case when $v = 1 then rate else 0 end as prob_${v}")

scala> val param = pivotedProb.mkString(",")

scala> val probs = spark.sql(f"select *, $param from df")

scala> probs.show()
+---+---+---+----+-----+------+------+------+
|  A|  B|  C|rate|total|prob_A|prob_B|prob_C|
+---+---+---+----+-----+------+------+------+
|  0|  0|  0| 0.0|    0|   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|
|  1|  0|  0| 0.1|    1|   0.1|   0.0|   0.0|
|  0|  1|  0|0.11|    1|   0.0|  0.11|   0.0|
|  0|  0|  1|0.12|    1|   0.0|   0.0|  0.12|
|  1|  1|  0|0.24|    2|  0.24|  0.24|   0.0|
|  1|  0|  1|0.27|    2|  0.27|   0.0|  0.27|
|  0|  1|  1| 0.3|    2|   0.0|   0.3|   0.3|
|  1|  1|  1| 0.4|    3|   0.4|   0.4|   0.4|
+---+---+---+----+-----+------+------+------+
```

which gives me the wrong output.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, using `foldLeft` to traverse the channel columns, you can 1) generate a `ratesMap` from the one-channel dataframe, and, 2) add columns to the two-channel dataframe with column values equal to product of channel and corresponding `ratesMap` value:

```
val df = Seq(
  (0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0),
  (1, 0, 0, 0.1, 1),
  (0, 1, 0, 0.11, 1),
  (0, 0, 1, 0.12, 1),
  (1, 1, 0, 0.24, 2),
  (1, 0, 1, 0.27, 2),
  (0, 1, 1, 0.3, 2),
  (1, 1, 1, 0.4, 3)
).toDF("A", "B", "C", "rate", "total")

val oneChannelDF = df.filter($"total" === 1)
val twoChannelDF = df.filter($"total" === 2)

val channels = df.columns.filter(v => !(v.contains("rate") || v.contains("total")))
// channels: Array[String] = Array(A, B, C)

val ratesMap = channels.foldLeft( Map[String, Double]() ){ (acc, c) =>
  acc + (c -> oneChannelDF.select("rate").where(col(c) === 1).head.getDouble(0))
}
// ratesMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(A -> 0.1, B -> 0.11, C -> 0.12)

val probsDF = channels.foldLeft( twoChannelDF ){ (acc, c) =>
  acc.withColumn( "prob_" + c, col(c) * ratesMap.getOrElse(c, 0.0) )
}

probsDF.show
// +---+---+---+----+-----+------+------+------+
// |  A|  B|  C|rate|total|prob_A|prob_B|prob_C|
// +---+---+---+----+-----+------+------+------+
// |  1|  1|  0|0.24|    2|   0.1|  0.11|   0.0|
// |  1|  0|  1|0.27|    2|   0.1|   0.0|  0.12|
// |  0|  1|  1| 0.3|    2|   0.0|  0.11|  0.12|
// +---+---+---+----+-----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: For creating the ratesMap, why did you first create ratesDF ? I mean why didn't you use oneChannelDF directly?

Comment: @Regressor, you're right that `ratesMap` can directly use oneChannelDF.  I created `ratesDF` initially when exploring a different approach and forgot to discard it later.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, can u provide some good documentation / example for foldLeft , because I am finding a hard time to understand the parameter that the function takes, and what operations once can perform on it.

Comment: Here's an [article](https://commitlogs.com/2016/09/10/scala-fold-foldleft-and-foldright/) about Scala's `fold` methods, and here's [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.4/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L155) that has `foldLeft`'s signature.

Comment: thank u, and what does the head.getDouble(0) part do ?

Comment: `oneChannelDF.select("rate").where(col(c) === 1)` returns a dataframe which can be regarded as a `List` of `Row`s.  To obtain the wanted rate column value, we use `head` to fetch the first row (which should be the only row given the channel == 1 condition) and `getDouble(0)` to cast the first element of the row (which should also be the only element) to a Double required for the Map value type.